# tangent subbundle which is not a distribtuion

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

Could you give me an example of a subbundle of a tangent bundle which is not a distribution?

What is the essential difference between distributions and subbundles?

Comment: A distribution is the same thing as a subbundle of the tangent bundle,
so your question is weird.  (There are "generalized" distributions, in which one allows the dimension of the fibers to vary, and those are certainly not subbundles, but those are much less popular than the usual ones.)

Comment: um.. thank you... i want to delete my question....

Comment: ah generalized version might be the one that confuses me. thanks